# SQL SELECT from three tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I have three tables:

```
Map_table
- id
- content_id
- from_user_id
- to_user_id
- timestamp

User_table
- id
- name

Content_table
- id
- title
```

eg: I want to select rows from the Map_table where Map_table.to_user_id = 1

and also provide the User_table.name where Map_table.from_user_id = User_table.id

and also provide the Content_table.title where Map_table.content_id = Content_table.id

Map_table.content_id might be null and therefore not map to the Content_table

If been through a load of answers here and still tearing my hair out to get the results I need.
Can any SQL gurus out there see a simple solution. The potential JOINs required are frying my brain.

Any help would be much appreciated. For the sake of my scalp, among other things ;)

Comment: From the desciption you're on the right track. What have you tried?

Comment: oddly I never got notifications of replies and just came back here to see.. meanwhile I finally managed to get it going using the same answer as Parkyprg's below ;) I'll try Justin's and see which is faster. Thanks for responding! Scalp is still intact.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT mt.*, ut.name, ct.title
FROM
     Map_table mt
INNER JOIN
     User_table ut on mt.from_user_id = ut.id
LEFT JOIN 
     Content_table ct on mt.content_id = ct.id
WHERE 
     mt.to_user_id = 1
```

Comment: add this at the end `WHERE m.to_user_id = 1` :)

Comment: This is what I ended up with. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT m.id,m.content_id,m.from_user_id,m.to_user_id,m.timestamp,u.name,c.title
FROM Map_table m
INNER JOIN User_table u ON u.id = m.from_user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Content_table c ON c.id = m.content_id
WHERE m.to_user_id = 1
```

Comment: He wants to filter where to_user_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mt.*, ut1.name
FROM map_table mt inner join user_table ut1 on mt.from_user_id = ut1.id
inner join user_table ut2 on mt.to_user_id = ut2.id
where mt.to_user_id = 1
```

You need to join against user_table twice to do this.